# How to design a document file format?

Tags: file, format, document

I would like to design a file format which includes content like inks (saved as points), texts, pictures, records and so on.

I can't find any useful guidelines about how to design a file format. Features to be considered are:

1. Partial Synchronization (can sync partial elements but not always sync the hole document)
2. Quick response (like email，when finish downloading the content,shows the content.And then continue to download the attachment)
3. Compatibility (when the file format upgrade, the lower version of parser can parse a part of document which it recognizes)

Maybe I can use XML to construct the document. Are there any guidelines or design patterns for beginner to learn the method of designing a file format.

Comment: you should think about NOT doing this. there are so much file formats, why not use an established file format? but your request is just like a kind of software ;)

Answer (score 0):

For maximum "compatibility", I'd reccommend a format consisting of labelled chunks, like TIFF. If the reading code ignores unknown chunks, then your 2.0 installations can still read 3.0 files (at least as much of it as they are able).

You can organize the chunks with a master "directory" chunk which describes the hierarchy and placement of elements (some kind of flattened tree).

A good source for more is [The Encyclopedia of Graphics File Formats.](http://amzn.com/1565921615) They're super-cheap on Amazon because the old edition has some pages of the TOC mixed-up.